# How to predict new variables for a new randomly generate dataset using multiple regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I have generate a MARS regression model using known soil property data collected from field samples across the great plains region. I reduced all variables down to 5 predictor variables (elevation, tpi, k_factor, precipitation and temperature) and a single dependent variable (soil organic content:SOC). I split the original data set to a training class and a test class. I was able to utilize my model to predict values on the test dataset after the model was created just fine.

I want to predict on a newly generated dataset with data derived from geospatial rasters across teh great plains region. I generated random samples based on the study are size and created a point shapefile over the area. The rasters were written into the points where they intersected to give me a table full of the 5 perdictor variables for each point. I do not have a SOC raster, so my new table is missing that column.

My intention was to predict the SOC values based on the 5 predictor variables in the new table. However, I keep getting an error " variable lengths differ" for each of my columns. I would like to export the predictions back to the new table to be able to visualize the distribution of SOC within GIS. Below is example of my code:

```
setwd("E:\\Fall19\\stats\\FinalProject\\Excel_tables")
table=read.csv("sel_el_train.csv")
attach(table)
my_data=table[,c(8,9,15,16,18,19)]


mars1 <- earth(
  SOC ~ ., data=my_data)
print(mars1)
summary(mars1)

plot(mars1)


predict(mars1, newdata=test.data)
```

Below are screen shots of the bottom of the record. You can see a difference of the number of records i built the model out of and the dataset I'm trying to predict on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if your test.data SOC columns have so many NAs, how is the model going to predict? How about removing rows with NAs in test.data?

Comment: The NAs are the default. IN the new data set, there are no SOC values for any record. I am trying to predict those values and write them into the dataset for each record. My model is basically estimating SOC as a function of the other variables. I would therefore think that i would be able to provide the predictor values and calculate the SOCs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The method I was using was very particular about heading spelling. My K_factor variable was not spelled correctly. Once all column names matched up, everything worked well.